# Preferred method for achieving specific CSS and/or JQuery slider layout effect

Tags: jquery, css, animation, carousel, sliders

**I have a wireframe that I am building.**

[image]

I have been searching for ways to achieve this slider format but my searches have been limited to carousel sliders that look different than the one I am building.

**A few links I have come across that have things that seem useful:**
apparently I need 10 reputation to share more than 2 links so I removed the prefixes from the links...

-css3.bradshawenterprises.com/sliding/

-jqueryrain.com/2014/12/bee3d-slider-touch-enabled-pure-js-plugin/

-cssslider.com/carousel-slider-17.html

-jqueryrain.com/demo/3d-slider-carousel/

-codepen.io/Rowno/pen/Afykb

-desandro.github.io/3dtransforms/docs/card-flip.html

**To Note:**

The site is built mostly using Bootstrap but Bootstrap seems to not have a method to achieve this slider format.

I have tried a couple of these methods already, such as **jquery's** .carousel() and .carouselSlider() but even though jQuery was loaded, I was getting errors saying that these were not functions and was not able to render the elements associated with the carousels.

As of now, I am back to square one, finding myself building this from scratch using custom position:absolute, top:, left: and z-index: CSS values, which seems highly inefficient because I will have to address the animation aspect of the slides, which this custom CSS does not currently support.

Also This might not be too important for now, while I am just trying to find the best and most efficient way to build this but these slides are supposed to be sequential for a step by step form process. (ie: user cannot go to the next slide until they have completed the current form/slide).

**A Few Questions:**

-What is the **most appropriate/relevant search terms** that describe my design?

- Is **"carousel slider"** the correct term or should I be looking for **animations/transitions**?

**My current code:**

```css
.tab{
 height:1em;
 width:5%;
 background-color: rgba(16, 185, 228, 0.8);
}

.rectangle {
 position: absolute;
 left:25%;
 top:40%;
 /*width: 641px;*/
 width: 50%;
 /*height: 250px;*/
 height: 18em;
 border-radius: 4px;
 margin-top: 1em;
 background-color: #f3f0f0;
 box-shadow: 0 0 6px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.rectangle-copy {
 position: absolute;
 left:-22%;
 top:-95%;
 width: 144%;
 height: 18em;
 z-index: -2;
 margin: 0 auto;
 border-radius: 4px;
 background-color: rgba(243, 239, 239, 0.6);
 box-shadow: 0 0 6px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
.rectangle-copy2 {
 position: absolute;
 left:-19%;
 top:-108%;
 width: 138%;
 height: 18em;
 z-index: -4;
 margin: 0 auto;
 border-radius: 4px;
 background-color: rgba(243, 239, 239, 0.6);
 box-shadow: 0 0 6px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
.rectangle-copy3 {
 position: absolute;
 left:-16%;
 top:-119%;
 width: 132%;
 height: 18em;
 z-index: -6;
 margin: 0 auto;
 border-radius: 4px;
 background-color: rgba(243, 239, 239, 0.6);
 box-shadow: 0 0 6px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.rectangle-copy4 {
 position: absolute;
 left:-16%;
 top:-119%;
 width: 128%;
 height: 18em;
 z-index: -6;
 margin: 0 auto;
 border-radius: 4px;
 background-color: rgba(243, 239, 239, 0.6);
 box-shadow: 0 0 6px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}



   fieldset {
      border: 0;
    }
    label {
      display: block;
      margin: 30px 0 0 0;
    }
    .overflow {
      height: 200px;
    }
```

```html
  <!-- for the blue tabs/dots -->
  <!-- <div id="tab-container">
    <div id="tab1" class="tab"></div>
    <div id="tab2" class="tab"></div>
    <div id="tab3" class="tab"></div>
    <div id="tab4" class="tab"></div>
    <div id="tab5" class="tab"></div>
    <div id="tab6" class="tab"></div>
    <div id="tab7" class="tab"></div>
    <div id="tab8" class="tab"></div>
  </div> -->

  <div class="rectangle">

    <div class="form-group col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2" style="margin-top:5em;">
      <center><label>Select your job</label></center>

      <select class="form-control">
        <option>&nbsp;</option>
        <option class="form-control">option 1</option>
        <option>option 2</option>
        <option>option 3</option>
        <option>option 4</option>
        <option>option 5</option>
      </select>
      <div id="rect2" class="rectangle-copy"></div>
      <div id="rect3" class="rectangle-copy2"></div>
      <div id="rect4" class="rectangle-copy3"></div>
      <div id="rect4" class="rectangle-copy4"></div>
      <div id="rect4" class="rectangle-copy5"></div>
    </div>

 </div>
```

**Conclusion:**

-So yeah, my code right now is obviously inefficient and will be a major headach when trying to integrate custom JS/JQuery code to get the actually slider animation/functionality to work.  There are several ways of doing this but asking around seems like the best move before I invest a lot of time into a set method that I end up finding out is objectively poor in choice.